# Help with Test Class for Before Insert Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class

I created a trigger for a custom object (Event Registration), before the record saves the trigger will search Salesforce for the contact in a certain record type, if it exists attach the contact. If not create a new one and then save the event registration. The trigger works in Sandbox but I can not get the coverage in the test class. Can someone please guide me and let me know what I am doing wrong? Should I create two separate test classes? I have not created a lot of apex triggers and I am not sure of the best way to do this. Thank you.

*Here is the trigger*

```
trigger EventRegistrationTrigger on Event_Registration__c (before insert) {
for (Event_Registration__c  EventRegistrationTrigger: Trigger.new)
// get account ID
Id accountId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Account Name'].Id;

// iterate through event registrations
for (Event_Registration__c eventRegistration : Trigger.new) {
    //Check if contact exists
    try { 
        // Run the query
        Contact existingContact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = :eventRegistration.FirstName__c AND LastName = :eventRegistration.Last_Name__c AND Email = :eventRegistration.Attendee_Email__c AND RecordTypeID = :eventRegistration.Contact_Record_Type__c LIMIT 1];
        eventRegistration.Contact__c = existingContact.Id;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // Debugging
        System.Debug('AMG DEBUG 1:' + eventRegistration.FirstName__c + ' || ' + eventRegistration.Last_Name__c + ' || ' + eventRegistration.Attendee_Email__c + ' || ' + eventRegistration.Contact_Record_Type__c);
        System.Debug('AMG DEBUG 2:' + ex.getMessage());
        
        //Create new contact
        Contact newContact = new Contact();
        newContact.FirstName = eventRegistration.FirstName__c;
        newContact.LastName = eventRegistration.Last_Name__c;
        newContact.Email = eventRegistration.Attendee_Email__c;
       // newContact.AccountId = accountId;
        newContact.RecordTypeId = eventRegistration.Contact_Record_Type__c; // pulled from a form with actual record type ID
        
        // insert a new contact
       insert newContact;
        
        //Set contact ID on event registration
        eventRegistration.Contact__c = newContact.Id;
    }
}
```

}

*Here is my test class in that I am only getting 14% coverage.*

```
@isTest
public class EventRegistrationTriggerTest {

@isTest
static void testEventRegistrationTrigger() {
    
    // Create a test account
    Account testAccount = new Account();
    testAccount.Name = 'Test Account';
    insert testAccount;
    
    // Create test contact record type
    RecordType testRecordType = new RecordType();
    testRecordType.Name = 'Test Record Type';
    testRecordType.DeveloperName = 'Test_Record_Type';
    testRecordType.SobjectType = 'Contact';
    insert testRecordType;
    
    // Create test event registration
    Event_Registration__c testEventRegistration = new Event_Registration__c();
    testEventRegistration.FirstName__c = 'Test';
    testEventRegistration.Last_Name__c = 'Contact';
    testEventRegistration.Attendee_Email__c = 'test.contact@test.com';
    testEventRegistration.Contact_Record_Type__c = testRecordType.Id;
    insert testEventRegistration;
    
    // Verify that a new contact record has been created
    Contact newContact = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email = :testEventRegistration.Attendee_Email__c AND RecordTypeId = :testEventRegistration.Contact_Record_Type__c LIMIT 1];
    System.assertEquals(testEventRegistration.FirstName__c, newContact.FirstName);
    System.assertEquals(testEventRegistration.Last_Name__c, newContact.LastName);
    System.assertEquals(testEventRegistration.Attendee_Email__c, newContact.Email);
    
    // Verify that the Contact__c field of the Event Registration record is set to the new contact's ID
    Event_Registration__c updatedEventRegistration = [SELECT Id, Contact__c FROM Event_Registration__c WHERE Id = :testEventRegistration.Id];
    System.assertEquals(newContact.Id, updatedEventRegistration.Contact__c);
    
    // Test with an existing contact
    Contact existingContact = new Contact();
    existingContact.FirstName = 'Existing';
    existingContact.LastName = 'Contact';
    existingContact.Email = 'existing.contact@test.com';
    existingContact.RecordTypeId = testRecordType.Id;
    insert existingContact;
    
    testEventRegistration = new Event_Registration__c();
    testEventRegistration.FirstName__c = existingContact.FirstName;
    testEventRegistration.Last_Name__c = existingContact.LastName;
    testEventRegistration.Attendee_Email__c = existingContact.Email;
    testEventRegistration.Contact_Record_Type__c = existingContact.RecordTypeId;
    insert testEventRegistration;
    
    // Verify that the Contact__c field of the Event Registration record is set to the existing contact's ID
    updatedEventRegistration = [SELECT Id, Contact__c FROM Event_Registration__c WHERE Id = :testEventRegistration.Id];
    System.assertEquals(existingContact.Id, updatedEventRegistration.Contact__c);
}
```

}

Comment: Your trigger has all kinds of issues - 1) It is doing soql inside a for loop; 2) It is using try-catch to detect whether Contact doesn't exist; 3) It is doing DML inside a for loop. Read up on bulkification

Comment: You should also read up on trigger frameworks. Even if you move the code out into a trigger handler, you have a lot of code in an exception handler, which makes it harder to test. Put the exception handling code (if you still need it) into a method that is called from the exception catch block. You can then also test the method directly.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I created seporate test classes and got the coverage I needed.